# Converting JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert a file(not really json) to a csv file, here is the code

```
import json
import gzip
import csv


def parse(path):
  g = gzip.open(path, 'r')
  for l in g:
    yield json.dumps(eval(l))


csvOut = gzip.open("meta_Musical_Instruments.csv", 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csvOut)

fields = ["asin"]

for product in parse("meta_Musical_Instruments.json.gz"):
  line = []
  for f in fields:
    if product.has_key(f): line.append(product[f])
    else: line.append("")
  writer.writerow(line)
```

Sample file is like this:

```
{'asin': '0014072149', 'related': {'also_viewed': ['B0058DK7RA'], 'buy_after_viewing': ['B0058DK7RA']}, 'title': 'Double Concerto in D Minor By Johann Sebastian Bach. Edited By David Oistrach. For Violin I, Violin Ii and Piano Accompaniment. Urtext. Baroque. Medium. Set of Performance Parts. Solo Parts, Piano Reduction and Introductory Text. BWV 1043.', 'price': 18.77, 'salesRank': {'Musical Instruments': 94593}, 'imUrl': 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41m6ygCqc8L._SY300_.jpg', 'brand': '', 'categories': [['Musical Instruments']], 'description': 'Composer: J.S. Bach.Peters Edition.For two violins and pianos.'}
```

after I execute the code, i got this error msg:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-1cb41fc12b41> in <module>()
     16   line = []
     17   for f in fields:
---> 18     if product.has_key(f): line.append(product[f])
     19     else: line.append("")
     20   writer.writerow(line)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Please help!

Comment: `json.dumps(eval(l))` What the whatty what?

Comment: Please extract a minimal example. Hardcode the file-content for that.

Comment: Eh, the problem is... mostly obvious. I like to understand what the asker is thinking at times though, so that I can give a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused about what `json.dumps()` does... JSON is a text format - a textual representation of your data. the `json` module let you either encode a Python object to json or decode a json string to a Python object. `json.dumps(python_obj)` does the Python to json encoding and returns a string. To decode from a json string to a Python object, you have to use `json.loads(json_string)`. IOW, you're `parse() function should look like:

```
def parse(path):
  g = gzip.open(path, 'r')
  for l in g:
    yield json.loads(l)
```

I cant tell if it will work without knowing what your "not really json" file contains, **but** that's definitely how you should use `json` to decode a json string into a Python object ;)

As a side note : the real use cases for `eval()` in Python are very very very rare - I've been programming in Python since the 1.5.2 days and never had to use it so far -, so if you find yourself using `eval` there's a 99.999% chances you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use double quotes not single quotes. JSON only allows for double quotes

`'key'` -> `"key"`

Comment: Yes, the asker has already noted that the input is not quite JSON.

Comment: Well he is parsing JSON so when he feeds the program a non-JSON object it becomes unhappy

Comment: They actually aren't. Besides, the error isn't complaining about that regardless.

Comment: ```'str' object has no attribute 'has_key'``` It seems to be looking for the attribute ```'has_key'``` which seems like it is looking for a JSON key, which is defined by double quotes. Is this not the case?

Comment: JSON is a string. `has_key()` is a `dict` method.

Comment: Ahh.. I see now, should he use ```.hasOwnProperty()```, or the Pythonic equivalent than? I am used to parsing CSV and JSON w/ JavaScript

Comment: That's what they're doing; they're just feeding it the wrong type.

Comment: @KyleChickering you still don't understand that `json.dumps(obj)` returns a **string**.